# Fetching WiFi adapters list in Windows 10 app fails

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, uwp

I have a Windows 10 universal app and I am trying to get the list of WiFi adapters:

```
var adapters = await WiFiAdapter.FindAllAdaptersAsync();
```

I have all the required permissions set up. This calls works once. Then when I close or kill the app, the call fails with

> An attempt was made to establish a session to a network server, but
>   there are already too many sessions established to that server.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800704C4)

The error message is strange, I do not know how to interpret or more importantly fix it.

Comment: I have faced exactly the same issue and after spending to much time trying to figure it out - end up with just catching it and ignore. With that sad sometimes it starts failing repeatedly, so I have to reboot or turn Wi-Fi "off" and back "on" to make it working in app again. This is not a solution for sure, but as a temporary workaround it seems to work fine so far. Also it seems like the root cause of the issue may be somewhere in WinRT API or even driver level. Anyway, please post a solution here if you find any. Good luck!

Comment: I am facing same issues please update if you find any good solution

Comment: [Official example](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/WiFiScan/cs/Scenario1_CachedNetworks.xaml.cs) mentions calling `WiFiAdapter.RequestAccessAsync` first. Does your code do it?

Comment: Mine does, but it doesn't change a thing, unfortunately.

Comment: Same issue here, but it does occur very randomly. Haven't found any solution yet, so for now i just catch the exception, but this is not a solution...

Comment: As of November 2019, still no solution, I also have the same exception thrown when using WiFiAdapter.RequestAccessAsync