# UWP App using Windows.Devices.WiFi

Tags: c#, windows, session, networking, uwp

I am writing a UWP app using the Windows.Devices.WiFi to basically get a lists of networks.  Everything was working fine when I retrieved the information a time or two.  However, I wanted to put the code into a timer so I can report regularly.  Once I did this, I got "an attempt was made to establish a session to a network server, but there are already too many sessions established to that server."

I am not sure what is establishing connections as I am just trying to read the information.  I am not even calling the ConnectAsync calls.

Can anyone help me out?  I need to know what to dispose, or close, etc.

Update:  Further analysis, I am finding that the call to FindAllAdaptersAsync multiple times is causing this issue.

Comment: Further analysis, I am finding that the call to FindAllAdaptersAsync multiple times is causing this issue.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34269468/fetching-wifi-adapters-list-in-windows-10-app-fails

Comment: Mine has nothing to do with Killing or starting the application as much as it does calling FindAllAdaptersAsync 10 times or so.

Comment: Without any code, it's hard to help

Answer (score 1):

I decided to cache up the list of adapters by only calling FindAllAdaptersAsync  once. Thanks for the idea Henk. This seemed to fix my issue for now.  However, I think that it is a bug with FindAllAdaptersAsync.  I would think you should be able to call this as much as you like, unless maintaining the network connection is necessary every time. Or at least a way to free them up.

Answer (score 0):

This happens with **WiFiAdapter**.FromIdAsync too.

"*already too many sessions established to that server*", on the 20th call.

After n calls of WiFiAdapter.FromIdAsync, do **GC.Collect()**. It helps.

n must be < 20. For example, 10.